# Stored procedure with strings

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figured out how to use insert statement in a stored procedure.
I want to put data into a table

like this **(concept, a, b, c, d, e, f, g)**

but i want to get the result like this:

```
concept  a    b
concept  c    d 
concept  d    e 
concept  f    g
```

I think i need a string for this?
how can i create the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question is Kinda Vague but this should work you just need to insert multiple values in your table, to indicate a new row.

Sample:

```
INSERT INTO example
  (Concept, element1, Element2)
VALUES
  (Concept,a,b),
  (Concept,c,d),
  (Concept,e,f),
  (Concept,g,h);
```

output:

```
Concept | Element1 | Element2 // table headers
concept |    a     |  b
concept |    C     |  D
concept |    e     |  f  //table elements
concept |    g     |  h
```

or look [Here for more :)](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/)

Comment: aw sorry about vagueness. XD Im trying to use insert stored procedure.

Comment: You can try that :) just divide your inputs into multiple chunks to achive the desired result, try doing what i posted :)